# MongoDB error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodb-3.2

I'm setting up for test a dockerized MongoDB which uses SSL. Everything goes fine with configuration, but when I'm trying to connect I get the following error:

```
SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain.
```

Here's how I generate my CA and server/client certificates:

```
# CA
openssl genrsa -out ca/ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -key ca/ca.key -days 10000 -out ca/ca.crt

# Server
openssl genrsa -out server/mongodb.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server/mongodb.key -out server/mongodb.csr
openssl x509 -req -in server/mongodb.csr -CA ca/ca.crt -CAkey ca/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server/mongodb.crt -days 365
cat server/mongodb.key server/mongodb.crt > server/server.pem

# Client
openssl genrsa -out client/cl.key 2048
openssl req -new -key client/cl.key -out client/cl.csr
openssl x509 -req -in client/cl.csr -CA ca/ca.crt -CAkey ca/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client/cl.crt -days 365
cat client/cl.key client/cl.crt > client/cl.pem
```

Here's my MongoDB configuration file (disregard the file paths):

```
net: 
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  port: 28018
  ssl: 
    CAFile: /etc/mongo/ssl/ca/ca.crt
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/mongo/ssl/server/server.pem
    mode: requireSSL
storage: 
  dbPath: /mongo/db
  journal: 
  enabled: true
```

And here's how I'm connecting to it:

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 28018 --ssl --sslCAFile mongoconf/config/ssl/server/server.pem --sslPEMKeyFile mongoconf/config/ssl/client/cl.pem
```

The local `mongoconf/config` is mapped to `etc/mongo` in the container.

Comment: Make sure you check this out:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80859/issues-with-self-signed-certificates-ssl-and-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

You have the `--sslCAFile` pointing at the `server.pem` file rather than the CA file which seems to be in `/etc/mongo/ssl/ca/ca.crt`. As a result the cert you have generated for your client connection is not considered valid.

You have a couple of options, you can allow cert-less connections by clients (they are still SSL encrypted, just no cert to validate the client side). This is done by specifying the [`allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates) option on the server and is functionally equivalent to how `HTTPS` works on the web.

The other option of course is to fix the `sslCAFile` path to point at the CA cert rather than the server cert.

Comment: I also thought so. When I tried to use the actual CA certificate (actually, that's what I tried first) both for starting mongod on the server and mongo on the client, Mongo refused to connect with a Self-Signed Certificate Error. I found my cross-certificate solution on the web.